# InvalidKeyException java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: (null)

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I have two classes, one is main class and another is the implementation of AES.

However, in my AES class i have a method to decrypt a string, but whenever i run it, it gives an exception

My encryption method works just fine but my decryption method doesn't work as expected.

The code

```
private Cipher aesCipherForDecryption;
String strDecryptedText = new String();

public String decryptAES(final String ciphertext) {

    try {

        aesCipherForDecryption = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        aesCipherForDecryption.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iV));
        byte[] byteDecryptedText = aesCipherForDecryption.doFinal(byteCipherText);
        strDecryptedText = new String(byteDecryptedText);

    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        System.out.print("IllegalBlockSizeException " +e);
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        System.out.print("BadPaddingException "+e);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.print("NoSuchAlgorithmException "+ e);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        System.out.print("NoSuchPaddingException "+e);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        System.out.print("InvalidKeyException "+e);
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        System.out.print("InvalidAlgorithmParameterException "+e);
    }

    System.out.println("\nDecrypted Text message is " + strDecryptedText);
    return strDecryptedText;
}
```

The error this method outputs is

> InvalidKeyException java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: (null)

UPDATE #1:

So i have updated the code as the following

```
public String decryptAES(byte[] ciphertext) {
    String strDecryptedText = new String();
        try {
            byte[] byteDecryptedText = aesCipherForDecryption.doFinal(ciphertext);

            strDecryptedText = new String(byteDecryptedText);

        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            System.out.print("IllegalBlockSizeException "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            System.out.print("BadPaddingException "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    System.out.println("\nDecrypted Text message is " + strDecryptedText);
    return strDecryptedText;
}
```

and in the main class i have this line

```
byte [] byteciphertext = ciphertext.getBytes();
```

just to convert the string to bytes

is it correct? i'm still having

```
IllegalBlockSizeException javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipherjavax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

Could someone help me fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, are you sure that `secretKey` is not null?

Comment: Thank you for replying, i think i have fixed it because now i dont have that error comes up again but rather i have an error saying " Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded "IllegalBlockSizeException javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipherjavax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher"

Comment: Unfortunately you haven't posted a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I'd just be guessing, something I'm not strongly inclined to do.

Answer (score 9):

`secretKey` is clearly `null.`

Other problems:

- You aren't using the input parameter `cipherText`.
- The input parameter `cipherText` should be a `byte[],` not a `String`: cipher text is binary, and `String` is not a container for binary data.
- The result string `strDecryptedText` should be a local variable, not a member variable.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Could you have a look at my UPDATE#1 ?

Comment: @Deyaa That's an entirely different question, but a hint : n(in case you didn't get the hint of dot #2 yet)ot all bytes with a random value can be encoded as String. Use base 64 instead.

Comment: Exactly. You shouldn't have the ciphertext in a String in the first place.

Comment: @EJP Thank you, so the ciphertext should be of type byte[] from the main method. And the decrypt method should be in byte[]? or the parameter should only be in byte[] but the method should be of type string? because when the ciphertext is decrypted the method should return text not byte[]! Thank you again.

Comment: @Deyaa The plaintext can be a `String` if it doesn't consist of binary data.