# unable to encrypt my data using java JCE

Tags: java, security, encryption

I am using cryptography to encrypt my data.
I am using java 1.8.0_131 and `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` algorithm version 2.

In my local environment I am able to encrypt and the provider is found.
In my test environment which use the same java version i am getting the following exception:

`No installed provider supports this key: (null)`

we use byte array for the encryption
And the key is not null

what we did :

```
    public static byte[] encrypt(PublicKey publicKey, String algorithm, int keyVersion, byte[] clearData) throws EncryptionException {

       try {

           Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
           cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
           return addHeader(keyVersion, cipher.doFinal(clearData));

       } catch (Throwable t) {
           logger.error("Failed to encrypt data", t);
           throw new EncryptionException("Failed to encrypt data", t);
       }
   }
```

Why in my test environments the provider can't be found?

Thanks

Comment: Show your code please. Looks like the key you enter is `null`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InvalidKeyException java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: (null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517944/invalidkeyexception-java-security-invalidkeyexception-no-installed-provider-sup)

Comment: Hey thanks . if you mean the algorithm key , so no its for sure not null we have a log that indicates otherwise

Comment: And you have an exception that suggests it is null. Questions like this without code are off-topic and should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The public key was null because the path to the public key was incorrect.
our logs only writes the version of the public key which was not null . 
so we missed that one .